# Can you install a repo as a yum dependency?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum

I believe the answer is no, and I understand the security implications, but I just want to make sure I am not crazy. It's hard to believe no one has asked this before, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

A package can depend on another package which happens to install a repo file, such as epel-release, but it will not actually be used during that run of yum because it hasn't been installed yet.

Comment: This.  Note that other package management systems (like `apt` on Debian) can do the same, for example the `google-chrome-stable` package adds the Google repo for updates, etc to Chrome.